# How to create polyhedron mesh using reactphysics3d

Tags: c++, game-engine, game-physics, physics-engine

I am using reactphysics3d library https://github.com/DanielChappuis/reactphysics3d

I am trying to create a square pyramid as a polyhedron mesh - 4 outer triangular faces and two base triangular faces.

I am able to successfully create the polygon vertex array, but I am having problems with the polyhedron creation stage.

I am following the progression of shape creation as outlined in the user manual.

I would appreciate help with this!
Thanks

This is my code - I tried using a triangular pyramid (triangle base with triangle faces) to create a triangular mesh and was able to do so. I was then able to create a concave shape.

However, I want to create a convex shape using a polyhedron mesh for a triangle pyramid with a square base.
Any advice would be appreciated!

```
//array of 5 points, 3 coordinates
        float vertices[15];
        for(int k=0; k<5; k++){
                std::string vert = "v" + std::to_string(k);
                vertices[3*k] = j3["data"]["vertices"][vert]["x"];
                vertices[3*k+1] = j3["data"]["vertices"][vert]["y"];
                vertices[3*k+2] = j3["data"]["vertices"][vert]["z"];
                std::cout << std::setprecision(8);
                std::cout << "added " << vertices[3*k] << "to index" << 3*k << std::endl;
                std::cout << "added " << vertices[3*k+1] << "to index" << 3*k+1 << std::endl;
                std::cout << "added " << vertices[3*k+2] << "to index" << 3*k+2 << std::endl;
        }


        //6 triangle faces
        int indices[18];

        //each face is defined through vertices (ccw)
        //face1
        indices[0] = 0; indices[1] = 2; indices[2] = 1;

        //face2
        indices[3] = 0; indices[4] = 2; indices[5] = 3;

        //face3
        indices[6] = 0; indices[7] = 4; indices[8] = 3;

        //face4
        indices[9] = 0; indices[10] = 1; indices[11] = 4;

        //face5
        indices[12] = 1; indices[13] = 2; indices[14] = 4;

        //face6
        indices[15] = 4; indices[16] = 2; indices[17] = 3;

        rp3d::PolygonVertexArray::PolygonFace* polygonFaces = new rp3d::PolygonVertexArray::PolygonFace[6];
        rp3d::PolygonVertexArray::PolygonFace* face = polygonFaces;

        //each face has 3 indices
        //6 triangles
        for (int f=0; f<6; f++){
                face->indexBase = f*3;
                face->nbVertices = 3;
        }

        std::cout << "created polygon faces" << std::endl;


        //create the polygon vertex array
        rp3d::PolygonVertexArray* pva = new rp3d::PolygonVertexArray(5, vertices, sizeof(float), indices, sizeof(int), 6, polygonFaces, rp3d::PolygonVertexArray::VertexDataType::VERTEX_FLOAT_TYPE, rp3d::PolygonVertexArray::IndexDataType::INDEX_INTEGER_TYPE);

std::cout << "polygon vertex array created" << std::endl;

        //create the polyhedron mesh
        rp3d::PolyhedronMesh* pMesh = new rp3d::PolyhedronMesh(pva);
        std::cout << "polyhedron mesh created" << std::endl;

        //create the convex mesh collision shape
        rp3d::ConvexMeshShape* convexMesh = new rp3d::ConvexMeshShape(pMesh);
        std::cout << "convex mesh shape created" << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you forget a face++ in the faces loop